# LLVM Link IR files with debugged information

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I have multiple `.cpp` files that I am converting into LLVM IR `.ll` and then trying to link them with `llvm-link` before the pass and I could easily link my files without debugging flag `-g`. However if I convert `.cpp` into `.ll` with debugging flag and then try to link it, it gives me an error regarding subprograms as follows :

`llvm-link: test.ll:228:224: error: invalid field 'subprograms'`

which I believe was generated because of the debug information. This is the same problem I get even when I try to run `opt` on my LLVM IR with debug information in it. Is there any alternate ways to link LLVM IR that has the debug Information in it.

P.S. I am using llvm 3.8

Comment: No idea how to fix the error, but if you want to know what a subprogram is, it's part of the DWARF debug information (a subprogram construct is created to describe each function).

Comment: Yup I know it contains most of the metadata